# How to change the output of an app

Tags: bash, text-processing

Sometimes we don't like the standard output of some applications, like `apt`/`pacman`.
so every time, I have this question: Can I change it to be better or colorize it?

I propose this simple situation below to work on real example:

```bsh
$ cat standard-app.sh

#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..4}
do
  echo "x = $i"
  // can also use read function or external app
done

$ bash standard-app.sh

x = 1
x = 2
x = 3
x = 4
```

but, I want to change the output immediately  to be like this (before program end):

```bsh
$ cat fork-app.sh

#!/bin/bash
bash standard-app.sh| ...| ...

$ bash fork-app.sh

value of x is equal to 1
value of x is equal to 2
value of x is equal to 3
value of x is equal to 4
```

In my opinion, it's required to use `tee` to output to file and `tail` to read the end of the file and `awk` to grep partner or `sed` to change the output.

Is there another way?

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just pipe the output of `standard-app.sh` to `sed`, `awk` or other suitable tools to process it. The need of `tee` and `tail` is unclear to me.

Comment: `pacman` supports colours. You just need to enable it in `pacman.conf`. (`apt` output also has some colours now, IIRC.)

Answer (score 0):

```
bash standard-app.sh | awk '{printf "value of %s is equal to %s\n", $1, $3}'
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to clarify your requirements.